# MATLAB Inheritance - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: matlab, oop, inheritance, constructor

I was trying a simple example for inheritance in MATLAB.

I have 2 files Man.m and Worker.m as follows:

```
classdef Man
    properties
        salary;
        age;
    end
    methods
        function obj=Man(s,a)
            obj.salary=s;
            obj.age=a;
        end
        function monthly_salary=FactorBy12(obj)
            monthly_salary=obj.salary/12;
        end

    end
end
```

and

```
classdef Worker < Man
    properties
        years_at_organization;
    end
    methods
        function obj=Worker(y,s,a)
            obj.years_at_organization=y;
            obj.salary=s;
            obj.age=a;
        end
        function bonus=BonusToBeGiven(obj)
            bonus=obj.years_at_organization;
        end
    end
end
```

I am trying to inherit all of `Man` in `Worker` but it keeps throwing an error at me.
Man(5,6) works but Worker(5,6,7) doesn't. (`Input argument "s" is undefined.`)

Similar if I do something as simple as

```
classdef Woman < Man
end
```

Which according to [this](http://yagtom.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/objectOriented.html) guide is valid.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: suggestion: you might want to make `Man` class a handle-class instead of a value-class, by inheriting from `handle`: `classdef Man < handle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [superclass](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/hierarchies-of-classes--concepts.html) constructor expects arguments, you must [explicitly call](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/calling-superclass-methods-on-subclass-objects.html#bsa1tzj) it in the subclass:

```
classdef Worker < Man
    properties
        years_at_organization;
    end
    methods
        function obj = Worker(y,s,a)
            obj = obj@Man(s,a);               % call ctor of superclass
            obj.years_at_organization = y;
        end
        function bonus = BonusToBeGiven(obj)
            bonus = obj.years_at_organization;
        end
    end
end
```

The [implicit call](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-constructor-methods.html#brd2m9e-6) to the superclass constructor only works for the default ctor (one that doesnt expect arguments). A workaround is to allow for both cases by providing [default values](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-constructor-methods.html#brustg9) if applicable:

```
classdef Man
    ...
    methods
        function obj = Man(s,a)
            if nargin < 2, a = 20; end
            if nargin < 1, s = 1000; end
            obj.salary = s;
            obj.age = a;
        end
        ...
    end
end
```

Note that such a default constructor is necessary if you want to build an [array of objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-object-arrays.html):

```
>> m(5) = Man(5,3)
m = 
  1x5 Man array with properties:

    salary
    age
```

Comment: Thanks Amro. Do you know of a good guide for OOP in MATLAB. MATLAB's official documentation is pretty small and the guide in my question is pretty weak.

Comment: @Inquest: I find the official docs quite good and extensive, and I mostly learned from it... That and hanging around here on Stack Overflow :)